# How to convert composed Functions into a reactive pipeline?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I currently have a processing pipeline defined as a composition of `java.util.function.Function`s and I'd like to use it in a reactive context like calling it with `Flux#transform`. How should I modify `pipeline()`'s signature so that it fits as an argument to `Flux#transform`?

```java
Function<A, C> pipeline(UnaryOperator<A> f1,
    Function<A, B> f2_io,
    UnaryOperator<B> f3,
    UnaryOperator<B> f4_io,
    UnaryOperator<B> f5,
    Function<B, C> f6_io) {
  return f1.andThen(f2_io).andThen(f3).andThen(f4_io).andThen(f5).andThen(f6_io);
}
```

A first conversion attempt might be to only change the returned type from `Function<A, C>` to `Function<Flux<A>, Flux<C>>`:

```java
Function<Flux<A>, Flux<C>> pipeline(UnaryOperator<A> f1,
    Function<A, B> f2_io,
    UnaryOperator<B> f3,
    UnaryOperator<B> f4_io,
    UnaryOperator<B> f5,
    Function<B, C> f6_io) {
  return f -> f.map(f1).map(f2_io).map(f3).map(f4_io).map(f5).map(f6_io);
}
```

The big advantage here is that the signatures of `f1`..`f6` don't need to change. It would be fine if none of these functions did I/O operations, however, as their suffix hints, `f2_io`, `f4_io`, and `f6_io`, do potentially blocking I/O operations, so I think they should return `Mono`s.

If we change `Function<A, B> f2_io` to `Function<A, Mono<B>> f2_io`, we end up with a `Flux<Mono<B>>` after the second `map()`. How should the returned types of the following functions be changed? Can I avoid changing `UnaryOperator<B> f3` to `UnaryOperator<Mono<B>> f3`?

Comment: change map(f2_io) and map(f4_io) that return a Mono into flatMap(f2_io/f4_io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` transforms elements in a synchronous manner, in other words using map blocks on each operation until the evaluation finish. So `map` is not a suitable operator for blocking io. The family of asynchronous `flatMap` operators would be the right choice here.

If a function itself does not resturn a reactive type, you can always wrap the function in `Mono` to achive asynchronous execution without changing the function:

```java
Function<Flux<A>, Flux<C>> pipeline(UnaryOperator<A> f1,
                                            Function<A, B> f2_io,
                                            UnaryOperator<B> f3,
                                            UnaryOperator<B> f4_io,
                                            UnaryOperator<B> f5,
                                            Function<B, C> f6_io) {
    return f -> f.map(f1)
            .flatMap(v -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> f2_io.apply(v)))
            .map(f3)
            .flatMap(v -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> f4_io.apply(v)))
            .map(f5)
            .flatMap(v -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> f6_io.apply(v)));
}
```

Btw, there is a great tool [BlockHound](https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound) to detect blocking calls on non-blocking schedulers in reactive pipelines.